# Applying to a clients company

Tags: career-switch

I currently work at a contract software company and one of our clients is a very advanced medical simulation R&D center and i am the sole developer on one of their projects. I absolutely love the advanced technology they use and all of the work they do, so i want to apply to them but im not sure if i should.

My main concern is that if they see my resume and that I did the work on one of their projects(an important one), they may hire me specifically because it would be cheaper to have me work for them directly instead of through this contract company, thus cutting my current company out of the project. (Our contract states that this software is 100% theirs)

So..

1.) Is this unethical to leave my company for one of our clients? I know several employees in the past have moved on to other companies that we do work for so i dont think it is an issue but still interested in your input.

2.) Is it unethical for me to apply knowing they will probably be interested in hiring me specifically because they could save money on this project and pulling it out from my current company?

I do like everyone i work with here and i would never want to screw anyone here over, but i really *really* like all the advanced medical work that this other company does and would love to be part of it.

Any thoughts on what i should do or how i should handle this situation?

Comment: *sigh ethics.* **the real question is can they hire you?** if you are the sole developer, is there a clause in the contract between your current company and the client company prohibiting poaching of talent? only way to find out is to broach the topic with them.

Comment: That's a good point but as far as i can tell, we never have any items in our contracts with them regarding this. I know there have been several employees in the past that have moved on to companies that we do work for and have never heard any issue regarding this.

Comment: `I know there have been several employees in the past that have moved on to companies that we do work for and have never heard any issue regarding this` Maybe you never heard about it but what does the contract say about it?

Comment: You are working for a software company that hires itself out to other companies and you are working in the contract house's location, and not the client's location? You need to check your current contract to see if there's a non-compete clause. If the client company wants you, they may have to pay a fee to the contractor company.

Answer (score 4):

This actually happens pretty often.

For example, you might have a Deloitte consultant leave the company for one of their customers. From personal experience, Deloitte actually encourages this practice, as it means that they have a contact inside another company that would likely recommend Deloitte to the company the next time consulting services are needed.

Your situation sounds similar; you're a consultant for a client, and you want to leave to work full-time for that client. Hopefully your company would encourage that type of practice. Depending on your relationship with your current company, you'd probably recommend to contract to your software company the next time they're needed.

**However,** keep in mind that there could be non-poaching, non-competition, and/or non-disclosure agreements between you and your current company that could make you and the R&D company subject to heavy civil penalties if breached. Take a look at those agreements, and if there is any risk of breaching those agreements, talk about it with the R&D company to see what they think. If they still want to hire you, approach the topic with your boss, who could allow a written exception to occur.

Answer (score 2):

First refer to your employment contract.  Did yo sign a non-compete agreement?  That is what you are personally bound to.

I know a few contract agencies that have a 25% finders fee in the contract if you are hired.  That is a standard rate for a job hunter.  They don't want to create an adversarial relationship with you or the company if you go to work for the company but they also want some money as they are loosing income.

Contracts directly between the two companies are for the two companies to work out.

Ideally the new company would have a job posting for job you are interested in and apply to that.  Then mention to your contact you saw a job position and applied.